# Clickable link is too large for image

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, image-resizing

I have looked everywhere for days now and can't seem to figure out this problem with rescaling images (with css only) that are blown way out of proportion (this is for an assignment). The images are supposed to be stacked vertically on a left-side column with a body of text to its right, like this:

[image]

Here's the html (cannot be changed):

```
    <aside class = "left">
        <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>

        <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>


        <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
    </aside>
    <section class = "right">...
```

I want to maintain the aspect ratio of the images so I'm using percentages %. But every time I use this, the link still retains its huge size and thereby takes up a huge space inside the aside container. When I try to scale down the link itself, the image is reduced again and the problem persists. Here is my code:

```
aside.left{
  background-color: #777613;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  height: 180vh;
}
aside img{
  display:block;
  margin:20% 0 10% 0;
  height:20%;
  width:20%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

What am I doing horribly wrong? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <style>
    aside.left{
      background-color: #777613;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      /*padding: 0 2% 2% 2%; */
      float: left;
      margin-right: 0.5%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    aside img{
      display:block;
     /* margin:20% 0 10% 0; */
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      border:1px solid black;
    }

    aside.left{
      width: 50%;
    }
    section.right{
      width:40%;
    }
    aside > a{
      height:33.3%;
      margin:0px;
    }
    </style>
```

This might help. Sorry for the multiple class names.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the margin `top & bottom` for img too large i.e: 20% & 10% in `aside img` CSS. I reduced it to 0. Adjust it as per your requirement

```css
aside.left{
  background-color: #777613;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  height: 180vh;
}
aside img{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  height:20%;
  width:20%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<aside class = "left">
   <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/></a>
   <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>
   <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Jack you should not use images larger to your requirement but instead first make images fit to your requirement by tools such as Adobe Photoshop or other various tools available and then use it.

Second you should give margin at body rather than individual components to keep page at center. Otherwise this will ends purpose of keeping page at center.
For ***body*** you must keep css as

```
body{

                margin: 0;
                margin-left:2%;
                margin-right: 2%; 

}
```

here i kept margin-left:2%, otherwise best practice is that you give width to main container in which all elements of page reside and set margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;Setting margin 0 initially keep page sticked to top as you show in image.

Third give width to your aside element. css for ***aside*** element is as

```
aside.left{
  background-color: #777613;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 500px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    width: 15%;
}
```

here i set height:500px according to my convenience but you can set it your own according to your page structure.

css for ***link of aside*** is as

```
aside a{

    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}
```

here inline-flex will keep link within flex column and don't allow it to go outside. margin-bottom will separate images.

css for ***image in link*** is

```
aside a img{
  border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
}
```

here if you use ***aside img*** then it means all img element lie inside aside. Mean to say even if you use image directly under aside without putting in link then that also it render css for image under link. If you are sure to render same css to images inside link as well as outside link, then you can use aside img. It will play all right.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong CSS-selectors.
It will be better when u change `

```
aside img{
```

to

```
aside > a > img{
```

Comment: that doesn't actually change anything